# How to solve the logic behind this Coupon Code?

Tags: php, mysql

I am looking for logic to develop one time use of copun code using php and sql.

`tbl_coupon_code` is exclusively for one time use per user.

User enters the coupon code. then reduce the price of item accordingly, but I can't update the `tbl_coupon_code` field since purchase is not complete.

Without completing the purchase user enters the coupon code for another product and gets a reduction again. And after doing this multiple time times user goes completing purchases.

How to prevent multiple use of `tbl_coupon_code` using php and mysql?

In an e-commerce site, a certain user is given a coupon code and he can use it only once.

Coupons are stored in database against each user's id. Suppose the user adds a few products in the cart to make an order and enters the coupon and then clicks on the 'Pay Now' button and is redirected to the payment page.

But the user uses a trick and does not pay just at that moment for the order he has just made. Instead he goes on to make another order by adding few other products in his cart and then again uses the single-time coupon and clicks the payment button to go to the payment page.

User might use different devices to make use of same coupon code multiple times. I want this to be avoided. Now he makes payment for both the orders one after another and thus becomes successful to reuse the single-time coupon.

How to prevent the user from reusing the single-time coupon?

How to implement this logic using PHP and mysql?

Below the my coupon code table:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_rewards ( 
  tbl_coupon_id int(11) NOT NULL, 
  tbl_coupon_points int(11) NOT NULL, 
  tbl_coupon_exp_date varchar(20) NOT NULL, 
  tbl_coupon_code varchar(20) NOT NULL, 
  tbl_user_id varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
  tbl_coupon_status int(1) NOT NULL 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/?more_on=xron.net). See How to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It also very helpful to show in your Question an expected result, and quote any (exact) errors you are getting. You are expected to show any research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: Maybe you can check if coupon expired on checkout/payment page and if it is used do not process to payment of second order. Or you can set coupon status on applying coupon stage and consider it used unless user deletes previous order/cart.
It is hard to tell not knowing logic of your app.

Comment: My main problem which I am facing is how to re-activate coupon again if user leaves the website without making a payment or without deleting order.